# Sum of values in a list squared in Scheme

Tags: dictionary, lisp, scheme

I'm trying to have the following program work, but for some reason it keeps telling me that my input doesnt contain the correct amount of arguments, why? here is the program

```
(define (sum f lst)
   (cond
     ((null? lst)
       0)
     ((pair? (car lst))
      (+(f(sum (f car lst))) (f(sum (f cdr lst)))))
     (else
       (+ (f(car lst)) (f(sum (f cdr lst)))))))
```

and here is my input: `(sum (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 2 3))`

Thanks!

btw I take no credit for the code, Im just having fun with this one (http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/scheme/listsum.htm)

Comment: HINT: Where ever you are calling `sum` are you passing 2 arguments to it?

Comment: oops uploaded an outdated version of the program, i've fixed it now but the error remains, is this perhaps not the way to go?

Comment: HINT2: Now you are calling f with invalid number of arguments. I guess you are lost in parens :)

Comment: The purpose of SO is not to have other people count parens for you. Especially if this is a class project.

Comment: nah just me trying to learn a language with a different syntax, im sorry but i wasnt expecting anything other than hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're indeed passing the wrong number of arguments to the procedures `sum` and `f`, notice that the expressions `(sum (f car lst))`, `(sum (f cdr lst))` are wrong, surely you meant `(sum f (car lst))`, `(sum f (cdr lst))` - you don't want to apply `f` (a single-parameter procedure) to the two parameters that you're passing, and `sum` expects two arguments, but only one is passed. Try this instead:

```
(define (sum f lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         0)
        ((pair? (car lst))
         (+ (sum f (car lst)) (sum f (cdr lst))))
        (else
         (+ (f (car lst)) (sum f (cdr lst))))))
```

More important: you're calling the `f` procedure in the wrong places. Only one call is needed in the last line, for the case when `(car lst)` is just a number and not a list - in the other places, both `(car lst)` and `(cdr lst)` are lists that need to be traversed; simply pass `f` around as a parameter taking care of correctly advancing the recursion.

Let's try the corrected procedure with a more interesting input - as it is, the procedure is capable of finding the sum of a list of arbitrarily nested lists:

```
(sum (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 (2) (3 (4)) 5))
> 55
```

You should take a look at either [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) or [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), both books will teach you how to structure the solution for this kind of recursive problems over lists of lists.

Comment: thanks! i can see how silly my mistakes were now, scheme syntax is something im yet to get used to :) another thing, one of the conditions is pair? for car lst, can car also be more than just one value? according to the definition its the first value in a list?

Comment: the `pair?` condition serves for determining if `(car lst)` is a number or an element. `Car` can only have one value, but the value itself could be a list with more than one value